# JS - Как посчитать значение арифметического выражения из строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Пытаюсь сделать калькулятор. Работает он следующим образом:
При клике по цифре, она вписывается в переменную. При клике по знаку (+,-,*,/), они добавляются в ту же переменную что и цифра. В итоге получается к примеру:
var x = '18*2+3' 
Я хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии по знаку равенства, уравнение находящееся в переменной x было решено, как к примеру, если бы это было просто: 
 var x = 18*2+3. 
console.log(x);

Пробовал функцию Number и понял что делаю что-то не то.

Подскажите пожалуйста какими способами можно решить задачу и как можно автоматический увеличить высоту дива ('.example') при достижении определенного количества знаков?

```js
$(function() {

var numbers = 0;
var example = 0;

// Пот нажатии на кнопку с цифро, он появляется в нижнем "табло" калькулятора
$('.numBtn').click(function() {
 if (numbers.length >= 12) {
  return;
 } else {
  if (numbers == 0) {
   numbers = this.value;
  } else {
   numbers += this.value;
  }
 }
 $('.calcIn').text(numbers);
})

// При нажатии на знак +, - , * или /, цифра и нажатый знак урованения добавляются в переменную example.
$('.funcBtn').click(function(){
 example += ($('.calcIn').text())
 $('.desk').text(example+=this.value);
 numbers = 0
 $('.calcIn').text(numbers)
})



/*При нажатии на кнопку равно, результат примера находящегося в качестве строки в переменной example должен появиться в качестве текста в классе calcIn */
$('.equalBtn').click(function(){
// 
//
$('.calcIn').text(result);
})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="simpleCalc">

  <div class="scoreboard">
      <div class="desk"> 0</div>
   <div class="calcIn" id="text">0</div>
     
  </div>
  <table>
   <input type="button" class="button bigButtonC cButton" value="C">
   <input type="button" class="button topBtn CEbtn" value="CE">
   <input type="button" class="button topBtn funcBtn" value="x2">
   <input type="button" class="button topBtn funcBtn" value="del">
   <input type="button" class="button topBtn funcBtn" value="÷">

   <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn numBtn" value="7">
   <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn numBtn" value="8">
   <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn numBtn" value="9">
   <input type="button" class="button secLineBtn funcBtn" value="×">
   <br>

   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn funcBtn" value="%">
   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn numBtn" value="4">
   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn numBtn" value="5">
   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn numBtn" value="6">
   <input type="button" class="button thirdLineBtn funcBtn" value="−">

   <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn funcBtn" value="√">
   <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn numBtn" value="1">
   <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn numBtn" value="2">
   <input type="button" class="button fourthLineBtn numBtn" value="3">
   <input type="button" class="button bigButtonPlus funcBtn" value="+">

   <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn funcBtn" value="±">
   <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn commaBtn" value=",">
   <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn numBtn" value="0">
   <input type="button" class="button bottomLineBtn equalBtn" value="=">

  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Выполнить строку может `eval`, но - **eval is evil**. Лучше завести пулл, куда кидать данные вида: `[{type: 'number', value: 2}, {type: 'sign', value: '+'}, {type: 'number', value: 2}]`. И по кнопке "Решить" проходить по массиву выполнятором.

Comment: Это не уравнение

Answer (score 5):

В вашем случае подойдет использование функции [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), хотя ее использование крайне не рекомендуется в сообществе. Она создает из строки полноценное выражения для выполнения. Для простоты демонстрации я изменил ваш `div` в текстовый `input` (разница в коде только в том, что для инпутов нужно именять не `.text()`, а `val()`).

```js
$('.equalBtn').click(function() {
    let equation = $('.desk').val();
    let result = eval(equation);
    $('.calcIn').text(result);
});
```

Насчет высоты. Высота элементов сама легко регулируется при помощи CSS, достаточно задать ширину для блочного элемента. В вашем случае, если ответ будет слишком длинный и в одно "слово", то следует применить свойство overflow-wrap, которое как раз решает эту задачу.

```css
#text {
    width: 200px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Для демонстрации я добавил кнопку с отображением числа пи.

**Демо:** https://jsfiddle.net/w96k/regbLvbf/1/

Comment: Смысл копировать чужие ответы?

Comment: Простите, откуда я по вашему скопировал? Или вы меня обвиняете в копировании средств js?

Comment: Про `eval` уже двое упомянули, Вы не предложили ничего концептуально нового, что приводит к выводу - копипаста.

Comment: Никто не предоставил демо. Никто не ответил на вопрос с переносом. В любом случае не вижу ничего плохого в нескольких ответах.

Answer (score 1):

> The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

А увеличить размер элемента, это же обычный if:

```
if (символов_достаточно) element.style.height = '20px'; //например (или методами jquery)
```

**НО!**

> **eval() is a dangerous function**, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.
>
> **eval() is also generally slower** than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.

Корректнее (но не проще) написать свою функцию(ции), которая разбирает строку на токены и оперирует уже <числами> и <выражениями>, правильно определяет порядок вычислений.

Подробнее можно почитать по запросу "*лексический анализатор*" в поисковиках и в книжках по построению компиляторов.

Comment: Ну Вы загнули :) Зачем анализаторы и, тем более, компиляторы, если автор может изменить структуру и анализировать ничего не нужно?

Comment: Автор хотел посчитать выражение в строке :) То, что предложили Вы, это изменение архитектуры его приложения :)
Я попытался ответить на вопрос. Учить, как было бы лучше не входило в планы, к тому же на своих ошибках учиться куда интереснее ;)

Comment: Тогда Вы предложили ядовитый костыль, который обязательно [больно, ибо основа] аукнется при мало-мальском расширении; лучше сразу переписать, тем более что ещё ничего особо не сделано.

Comment: Этот костыль может стать для человека библиотекой для разбора строк-арифметических выражений, в которую он может добавить, например, скобки или переменные. Повторюсь, я пытался ответить на вопрос о том, как из строки вычислить выражение. Если менять логику, да, можно split() строку в нужном порядке, можно сразу записывать тип и значение лексемы, как Вы предложили. Да мало ли чего придумать можно: программирование - занятие творческое :)

Comment: Вот в этом и отличие хороших ответов от механических: хороший не только ответит, но и поделиться опытом/знанием как надо, чтобы, образно выражаясь, дать удочку, а не рыбу

Comment: Зачем самом писать,  е сои написано уже все?

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/)

В ней можно выполнять выражения:

```
math.eval('sqrt(3^2 + 4^2)')            // 5
math.eval('sqrt(-4)')                   // 2i
math.eval('2 inch to cm')               // 5.08 cm
math.eval('cos(45 deg)')                // 0.7071067811865476
```

[Песочница где можно попробовать](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/PdYYLK?editors=0010)